# How can I find an expert to help review my PhD thesis?

Tags: thesis

I need someone to peer review my thesis.  My supervisor does not have enough time to fix my thesis. In addition I am holding all things by myself.

I need someone who is expert in this field.
**How can I find someone to help review my PhD thesis?**

Comment: Your advisor shouldn't *fix* your thesis, but I hope he has agreed to at least *read* your thesis and give you feedback.

Comment: In addition to your advisor, you can also ask the other members of your thesis committee for feedback.

Comment: Such review is exactly the job of your advisor and thesis committee. What else would their job be? I do not understand the situation at all...

Comment: you can use services that are recommended by publisher, I am not sure if it is allowed to bring out names,

Answer (score 5):

After your supervisor, your best bet is to ask people in your research lab/team if they can review your thesis. A PhD thesis usually talks about specific and sometimes complex scientific concepts. Therefore, even PhD students from other research groups won't have the necessary background to review it. Alternatively, you can ask someone you trust from outside your research lab/team who's research is closely matched to your own.

Note: I didn't include "asking other faculty" because that would be an irrational request (it is not their job and you already have an advisor) unless your current advisor formally suggests this approach.